# docker: connecting to MySQL from one container to another

Tags: mysql, docker

I have 2 docker containers running on the same physical host. One runs a MySQL server. I want to connect to that MySQL server from the other container. I link the 2 containers and I try and connect with:

```
mysql -h 172.17.0.3 -u root -p
```

and it fails with:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.3' (111)
```

If I go into the container running MySQL I can connect fine.

I have seen many, many posts with people having the same issue, but none of those answers have helped me.

I do the same thing between the same 2 containers with other services on other ports and they all work.

When I run nmap on the port I get this:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp closed mysql
```

Whereas for the other services that work I get:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5820/tcp open  unknown
```

If I run tcpdump on the container running MySQL (172.17.0.3) and try to connect from the other container (172.17.0.4) I see this:

```
15:52:57.048838 IP 172.17.0.4.47550 > 91fa9dcbc2a9.mysql: Flags [S], seq 3355905714, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 890919597 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:52:57.048874 IP 91fa9dcbc2a9.mysql > 172.17.0.4.47550: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3355905715, win 0, length 0
15:52:57.050627 IP 91fa9dcbc2a9.47225 > 192.168.10.3.domain: 14265+ PTR? 4.0.17.172.in-addr.arpa. (41)
15:52:57.064719 IP 192.168.10.3.domain > 91fa9dcbc2a9.47225: 14265 NXDomain 0/0/0 (41)
15:52:57.064933 IP 91fa9dcbc2a9.39489 > 192.168.10.3.domain: 28024+ PTR? 3.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (43)
15:52:57.077012 IP 192.168.10.3.domain > 91fa9dcbc2a9.39489: 28024 NXDomain 0/0/0 (43)
```

There is no firewall running on the host. Anyone have any ideas about why this is not working and/or how I can troubleshoot it further?

As requested, Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster
MAINTAINER Larry Martell <larry.martell@gmail.com>

ENV HOME /opt/django/CAPgraph/

RUN echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian buster main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN (apt-get update -y && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --force-yes build-essential git python python-dev python-setuptools nginx sqlite3 supervisor def
ault-mysql-server default-libmysqlclient-dev vim cron unzip software-properties-common python2.7 openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java openjdk-8-jre xvfb wkhtmltopdf 
sendmail-bin sendmail r-cran-ggplot2 r-cran-caret net-tools traceroute nmap tcpdump)
RUN (easy_install pip &&\
  pip install uwsgi)

ADD . /tmp/CAPgraph
RUN cp -rp /tmp/CAPgraph/* $HOME
RUN pip install -r $HOME/requirements.txt

# stardog
ENV STARDOG_HOME /AppData/stardog_knowledgegraph
ENV STARDOG_JAVA_ARGS "-Xms10g -Xmx10g -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10g"
ADD deploy/stardog/stardog-license-key.bin $HOME/deploy/stardog/stardog-license-key.bin
ADD deploy/stardog/init $HOME/deploy/stardog/init

# install utilities
COPY deploy/util /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/reset_CAPgraph /usr/local/bin/start_CAPgraph /usr/local/bin/stop_CAPgraph

RUN (echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf &&\
  rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default &&\
  rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django.conf &&\
  ln -s /opt/django/CAPgraph/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/)

RUN chown -R root:root $HOME
RUN chmod 777 $HOME
RUN chmod 777 /opt/django

VOLUME ["/opt/django/CAPgraph"]
EXPOSE 80 8006 443 3306
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/backupMySQL
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/backupMySQL
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

CMD ["/opt/django/CAPgraph/run.sh"]
```

And docker run command:

```
sudo docker run -d --restart=always -v /home/lmartell/devel1/Repos/CAPgraph:/opt/django/CAPgraph -v /home/lmartell/devel1/AppData/mysql_CAPgraph:/var/lib/mysql -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime -v /home/lmartell/devel1/AppData/cap_data:/AppData/cap_data -v /home/lmartell/devel1/bin:/opt/bin -v /home/lmartell/devel1/AppData/stardog_knowledgegraph:/AppData/stardog_knowledgegraph -p 18080:80 -p 18000:18000 -p 15820:5820 -p 3306:3306 --name devel1 elucidbio/capgraph:devel
```

And run command from other container I am connecting from:

```
sudo docker run -d --restart=always --link devel1 -v /home/lmartell/devel1/AppData:/AppData -v /home/lmartell/devel1/AppData:/projects -v /home/lmartell/devel1/Repos/CAPbase/capcompute:/opt/capcompute -v /home/lmartell/devel1/Repos/CAPgraph:/opt/CAPgraph -v /home/lmartell/devel1/Repos:/opt/django -v /home/lmartell/devel1/bin:/opt/bin -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime -v /bartok_SDBexports:/bartok_SDBexports --name capcompute-devel1 capcompute:latest
```

Comment: It'd help if you post your docker run commands, dockerfile, and compose (if being used)

Comment: Added docker file and run commands. Not using compose.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use IP Addresses to refer to the services internally. If you create a mysql service container and assign it a name of "db" you can access it via the name "db" in your other container.

I would also recommend first creating a new docker network, assigning your containers to it during your docker run statement, and then you should no issues with intercommunication.

This was originally only available for docker services, but they added the functionality in order to deprecate links.

Comment: When you say I can access it via the name, are you saying that would work for the -h host argument to mysql? As far as creating a new docker network, perhaps that is a better way, but right now we have urgent issues to solve, and what I am doing works with other ports and services, so I think it should work with mysql port 3306. I don't want to make major changes right now.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that if you have a container (mysql) and a container (php for example). If you name the mysql container mysql and the php container "application", you should be able to resolve the address of the mysql container via its name. This would work for the -h component of the mysql client, or any other connection that required an IP / DNS name to connect.

Comment: When I mention a Docker network, I'm also not talking about a physical network. Just a Docker application network. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Comment: I tried that, e.g.: `mysql -h devel1 -u ...` and it did not work. And yes, I realize you are not talking about a physical network.